# Why are these 2 ways of finding eigenvectors different in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy, eigenvector

```
import numpy as np
#first way
A = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [-2, 1, 0]])
print(A)
B = A@A.transpose()
print(B)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(B)
print(eig_vec)

#second way
from sympy import * 
G = Matrix([[2,-2], [-2,5]])
print(G.eigenvects())
```

Why does these two ways give different result when they are aiming a same goal of finding the eigenvectors?

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique

Comment: The eigenvectors are linear multiple of one another between the two approaches.

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned that eignevectors are only unique upto a scalar multiple. That's a mathematical fact. To dig into the implementations of the methods you're using, [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) returns *normalized eigenvectors* (i.e. the norm of the vectors would be 1) whereas `eigenvects()` of `sympy` does not normalize the vectors.

In some sense, normalized vectors are unique precisely because they have unit norm. They can define a unit eigendirection (geometrically), just like unit vectors in coordinate geometry. (Not strictly important to know)